# Linux Mint: permission denied на общедоступный каталог

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Есть каталог /media/norden которому права настроены для доступа под любым пользователем (drwxrwxrwx).
Но при попытке зайти в него под www-data получаю permission denied.
Что не так?

```
norden@norden-hp /media $ ls -l
итого 4
drwxrwxrwx+ 4 root root 4096 окт 25 15:23 norden
norden@norden-hp /media $ cd norden/
norden@norden-hp /media/norden $ cd ..
norden@norden-hp /media $ 
norden@norden-hp /media $ sudo -u www-data -s /bin/bash
...
www-data@norden-hp /media $ cd norden/
bash: cd: norden/: Отказано в доступе
www-data@norden-hp /media $
```

Update: в итоге проблема решилась удалением ACL у каталога (команда sudo setfacl -b norden).

Comment: А на каталог /media какие права?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 авг  7  2016 media

Comment: Эм, я вижу, что права принадлежат `root`. Или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: @Suvitruf но при rwxrwxrwx это ничего не значит

Comment: Зато что-то значит плюс, стоящий после всего этого. Гугл говорит, что это какой-то дополнительный ACL, но я с таким никогда дела не имел

Comment: @andreymal Да! Удаление ACL решило проблему.

Comment: @Norden, ответы - в ответы, а не в вопрос. Впрочем, считаю, что это решение так себе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась удалением ACL у каталога

```
sudo setfacl -b norden
```